# Impulsive forces

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, classical-mechanics

A force $F$ acting from time $t_1$ to $t_2$ on an object causes a change in its momentum $p$, as in $$\int_{t_1}^{t_2}Fdt=p(t_2)-p(t_1)$$

If this expression is now differentiated with respect to time, the result is an equation involving three forces $$F=\dot{p_2}(t_2)-\dot{p_1}(t_1)$$

But what exactly are these three forces? My interpretation, is that $F$ is the force which acts over a time period $dt$. This $F$ is not necessarily constant in time. The forces $\dot{p_1},\dot{p_2}$ represent the forces measured at times $t_1$ and $t_2$ respectively. As such, they have static values. Is this correct?

Comment: You’ve differentiated incorrectly. None of the terms in your first equation are functions of $t$. Each one is simply a number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You made a differentiation mistake.

To properly differentiate, you'd need to set up your integral as follows: $$\int_{t_0}^t F\ \mathrm d T=p(t)-p(t_0)$$ where $T$ is just a dummy variable. Differentiating, you get
$$\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt} \int_{t_0}^t F\ \mathrm d T=\dfrac{\mathrm d}{\mathrm dt}\left[p(t)-p(t_0)\right]$$ which becomes $$ F(t)=\dot p(t)$$ as you'd expect.